# How can I save value of user-defined in the database without clicking the save button

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created a user-defined field (Last Activity Date) on the Opportunities (CR304000) screen which is populated from the last Start Date of the activity on the Activities tab of the Opportunities screen (CR304000) on RowSelected as shown on screenshot one. When an activity is added for an opportunity, the user is not required to click the save button on the form of the opportunity, therefore the user-defined field I have added does not save the value to the database. I would like the value of the user-defined field to be saved  to the database whenever an activity is added to the opportunity and the value of the user-defined field changes without having to click the save button on the opportunity form as I need to use it on a generic Inquiry.

**Screenshot 1**
[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```
protected void CROpportunity_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
      
      var row = (PX.Objects.CR.CROpportunity)e.Row;
            if (row == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            CRActivity cRActivity = PXSelect<CRActivity, Where<CRActivity.refNoteID, Equal<Required<PX.Objects.CR.CROpportunity.noteID>>>, OrderBy<Desc<CRActivity.startDate>>>.Select(Base, row.NoteID);
            if (cRActivity == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            CROpportunityExt cROpportunityExt = row.GetExtension<CROpportunityExt>();
            cROpportunityExt.UsrLastActivity = cRActivity.StartDate;


            Base.Opportunity.SetValueExt<CROpportunityExt.usrLastActivity>(Base.Opportunity.Current, cROpportunityExt.UsrLastActivity);
           
            
            Base.Save.SetPressed(true);
           

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, push the value to the opportunity instead from the CRActivityMaint graph in the CRActivity RowPersisted event instead of pulling it from the activity in CROpportunity RowSelected. It is not good practice to change values of DAC rows in the RowSelected event.

Your code would be as follows

```
In CRActivityMaintExt

In RowPersisted

if (!(e.Row?.EntityDescription?.ToLower().Contains("opportunity") ?? false)) return;

CROpportunity opportunity = SelectFrom<CROpportunity>.Where<CROpportunity.noteID.IsEqual<@P.asGuid>>.View.Readonly.Select(Base, e.Row.RefNoteID);

if (opportunity is null) return;

var oppExt = opportunity.GetExtension<YourExtension>();

oppExt.YourValue = e.Row.SomeValue;

Base.Caches<CROpportunity>().PersistUpdated(opportunity);
```